# How do you tell which dll your c# application is using?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have an application which uses a .dll which is full of gui application code in location x. It use to have 1 button in, but now has 2.

When i start my application what i expect to see is a gui with 2 buttons, however i see a gui with 1 button. i have rebuild my gui .dll but it is magically using an older version from somewhere. If i try and debug my code it says that the version of code i am using is different from the one in the .dll

My question is, "How can i find out where it is looking for the .dll and why would it be using an old version as i only have 1 place where i compile the .dll to?"

Also wanted to state that i have it referenced and it is the correct version which has the 2 buttons in.. but when i run it is using another version???

Comment: How do you reference the dll? Have you deployed it into the bin directory or used COM or put it in the GAC?

Comment: How do you reference the DLL in your project? You may try to right-click the reference, open its Properties and check/uncheck the Copy Local switch. Such issues are quite often resolved through complete rebuilds of everything and restarts of the Visual Studio.

Comment: I simplified the question a little. My main program loads a plugin file which has a dll in which references the dll i am after. It is stored in a builds directory. The thing which confuses me is i have deleted all references to the old one, yet it keeps getting loaded up. I will try this module window to see if that sheds any light about all loaded assemblies and their locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio open the Modules window, Debug->Windows->Modules (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and this will list all loaded assemblies.

You can also at run time use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and walk the list looking at each `Assembly.CodeBase`.

If all else fails you can also use **Process Monitor** from Sysinternals http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 and watch which dlls are loaded by your process, but you'll be filtering out tons of output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging you can open the **Modules** window (**Debug** > **Windows** > **Modules**). This will show you all the executable files loaded into your process including the name and full path. You should then be able to figure out from where an out-of-date DLL was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial) in the `System.Reflection` namespace:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("your-assembly-name");
```

And then examine the `assembly` object for version info.