# How can I filter a breakpoint on an exported function of a module, based on the name of other modules that call that function?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, module, breakpoints

I am debugging a process in Visual Studio 2017 that loads many modules, I have set a function breakpoint on the CreateFile of Kernel32.dll.
This breakpoint hits many times, but I want to break the execution if a specific module makes call to the CreateFile function.
Passing unwanted breaks with F5 is not possible (there are too many of them).
There is no any code, all are just assemblies.
I want to see when "bcript.dll" (one of items in modules window) calls "CreateFile" from "Kernel32.dll".

[image: Visual Studio debugging Cortana.exe]

As I didn't find any solution for my question, I decided to use other tools than Visual Studio, then I found some useful tools that I want to share:

1- In my case I used windows hooks:

```
void CInstallerDlg::OnBnClickedInstall()
{
    if (m_hHook == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CString strTarget;
        GetDlgItem(IDC_TARGET)->GetWindowText(strTarget);
        HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"Dll.dll");
        if (hDll)
        {
            HOOKPROC hProc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hDll, (char*)1);
            if (hProc)
            {
                FARPROC SetTarge = GetProcAddress(hDll, (char*)2);
                if (SetTarge)
                {
                    ((void (CALLBACK *) (CString))SetTarge)(strTarget);
                    m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, hProc, hDll, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2- [sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) have lots of analyzing tools.

3- [winapioverride32](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/) allows monitoring and overriding api calls.

4- [snowman](http://derevenets.com/) is a PE decompiler.

5- [LordPE: download link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/LordPE.shtml) allows to view and edit binary data in PE sections, along with general details about PE.

Comment: could you share a screen shot about the breakpoint and the main code? Why the breakpoint was hit for many times, as you said that you set the function breakpoint, do you use the Conditional Breakpoints or data breakpoint or others in your side? In addition, please share the detailed information about "if a specific module makes call ", this module means a specific class or an assembly or others?

Comment: Breakpoints hits many time because many modules call this function. My breakpoint is "Function Breakpoint".

Comment: No direct solution, one idea is that whether you can write code which could make sure certain dll file or assembly was loaded, and then just add the function breakpoint during it was loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003863/how-do-you-tell-which-dll-your-c-sharp-application-is-using

Comment: The dll is loaded early in the beginning of process (close to load-time) and the calls to function happens much later.

Comment: if we couldn't control the time when the dll file loaded, I think it is hard for you to know when the function was called by it. Which kind of app did you develop? Maybe I could help you add certain developing tag to get help. If you use the debugger tool of VS directly, I also have no good solution.

Comment: I don't have the source code or even pdb files for these assemblies. I just wanted to analyze their behavior.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, if you want to use certain tools, like the Debug Diagnostic Tool : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx, the DebugDiag makes it easy to set breakpoints on function calls. Or the profile tool in VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx, which also could help us analyze the function calls. My previous understanding is that you just want to use the VS debugging with breakpoint. My misunderstanding, anyway, thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: You could also share your solution as the answer and mark it if this issue has been resolved, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue as yours research and find the answer easily. Of course, any VS debugging issue, we can discuss together:)

Comment: I am still interested to see if it can be done with breakpoints. That's why I am waiting for answer, not for my problem (it already solved) but to learn.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will keep opening this case for you. But since the dll was loaded before the project debugging, it is hard for us to know when the dll file called the function unless you could add breakpoint before the dll file will call the function, and then debug it using step Into.